# exponential random numbers with a bound in matlab

Tags: matlab, statistics, exponential

I want to pick values between, say, 50 and 150 using an exponential random number generator (a flat hazard function). How do I implement bounds on the built-in exponential random number function in matlab?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Maybe add a formula?

Answer (score 2):

A quick way is to a sequence longer than you need, and throw out values outside your desired range.

```
dist = exprnd(100,1,1000);
%#  mean of 100  ---^  ^---^--- 1x1000 random numbers
dist(dist<50 | dist>150) = []; %# will be shorter than 1000
```

If you don't have enough values after pruning, you can repeat and append onto the vector, or however else you want to do it.

Answer (score 2):

`exprandn` uses `rand` (see `>> open exprnd.m`) so you can bound the output of that instead by reversing the process and sampling uniformly within the desired range `[r1, r2]`.

```
sizeOut = [1, 1000]; % sample size
mu = 100; % parameter of exponential 
r1 = 50;  % lower bound
r2 = 150; % upper bound

r = exprndBounded(mu, sizeOut, r1, r2); % bounded output    

function r = exprndBounded(mu, sizeOut, r1, r2);

minE = exp(-r1/mu); 
maxE = exp(-r2/mu);

randBounded = minE + (maxE-minE).*rand(sizeOut);
r = -mu .* log(randBounded);
```

The drawn densities (using a non-parametric kernel estimator) look like the following for 20K samples

[image]